# Using Variable from Props vs Passing Prop as Argument in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In terms of writing components, which would be the preferred way to write below component? Assume that `removeCard` is outside of shown scope, ie. redux action.

My assumption would be that `ComponentCardB` would be, as it avoids passing an unnecessary argument which would be in the scope anyway. I imagine in terms of performance in the grand scheme of things, the difference is negligible, just more of a query in regards to best practise.

TIA

```
const ComponentCardA = (id) => {
  const handleRemove = (cardId) => {
    removeCard(cardId);
  };

  <div onClick={() => handleRemove(id)} />;
};

const ComponentCardB = (id) => {
  const handleRemove = () => {
    removeCard(id);
  };

  <div onClick={handleRemove} />;
};
```

Comment: In both cases, it would be `({id}) =>` rather than `(id) =>`. Your component receives an object with the properties.

Comment: Yes you're right, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The second option is better way because using an arrow function in render creates a new function each time the component renders, which may break optimizations based on strict identity comparison.

Also if you don't want to use syntax with **props.id** you rather create function component with object as parameter:

```js
const Component = ({id}) => { /* ... */ }
```

Of course using arrow function is also allowed but remember, when you don't   have to use them then don't.

Comment: *"...because using an arrow function in render creates a new function each time the component renders, which may break optimizations based on strict identity comparison..."* The OP's code creates `handleRemove` just as often as it would create that arrow function, so that's no more true of the arrow function than it is of `handleRemove` (though `handleRemove` is more susceptible to memoization).

Comment: In this case, you are right because it is a simple example, but in a larger component with more functions it can make a difference :)

Answer (score 1):

With functional components like that, yes, there's no reason for the extra layer of indirection in `ComponentCardA` vs `ComponentCardB`.

---

Slightly tangential, but related: Depending on what you're passing `handleRemove` to and whether your component has other props or state, you *may* want to memoize `handleRemove` via `useCallback` or `useMemo`. The reason is that if other props or state change, your component function will get called again and (with your existing code) will create a new `handleRemove` function and pass that to the child. That means that the child has to be updated or re-rendered. If the change was unrelated to `id`, that update/rerender is unnecessary.

But if the component just has `id` and no other props, there's no point, and if it's just passing it to an HTML element (as opposed to React component), there's also probably no point as updating that element's `click` handler is a very efficient operation.

Comment: Ok thanks, makes sense to me.

Re. memoization - haven't come across this so will head down that wormhole...